# Explorer does not show folder if started with path dirname of file location

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, explorer

With Python 3.4.2 on Windows I want to open the explorer with the folder of the currently running script like this:

```
import os, subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['explorer', os.path.dirname(__file__)])
```

Instead I see that the explorer is opened by with a default folder
"C:\Users\XX\Documents" and an error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/XXX/YYY.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(['explorer', os.path.dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 561, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['explorer', 'C:/XXX']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

and although `os.path.dirname` returns paths with slashes on Windows (backslashes are path seperators) you can copy and paste it into the explorer and it will open the location just fine. (XXX is the path part, YYY the file name part)

Furthermore, if you manually write the path as it is in the explorer (with backslashes), even then the command fails.

```
subprocess.check_call(['explorer', r'C:\Users'])
```

But at least the explorer will open the right directory despite of throwing the same error (so maybe using `call` instead of `check_call`).

What's going on here? How can I show the folder of the running Python script file in the explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the absolute path to the directory by calling `os.path.abspath`, and switch `check_call` with `call` (as you suspected).

```
import os
import subprocess
dirname = (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
subprocess.call(['explorer', dirname])
```

`subprocess.check_call` raises an exception if the return code of the process is nonzero.  Even when explorer doesn't actually have an error, it has a non-zero return status, so you get an exception.

That's actually unrelated to the problem, though.  The problem is that you were passing a string with forward slashes to explorer.  This would have happened if you called your script like `python path/to/script.py` instead of python `path\to\script.py`.  If you pass the **absolute path** to subprocess.call, explorer will open in the right directory.  You would get the same error if you passed an empty string as the second arg to subprocess.call.

Comment: _"you were passing an empty string"_ disagrees with the error message of `Command '['explorer', 'C:/XXX']' returned non-zero exit`...

Comment: Applying `os.path.abspath(__file__)` and using `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.check_call` fixes my problem. Thank you. However, it's not because the path was empty (it wasn't), but just because `abspath` converts slashes to backslashes. Even then the unnormal exit code of explorer remains but as long as it shows the right folder I won't complain...

Comment: @Trilarion and Eric  You two are both totally correct; I've updated my answer.  I tricked myself, because you do get the same symptoms if you send an empty string.  Big dumb me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use backslashes in your paths for windows explorer to undestand them. Testing from the command line, this works:

```
> explorer C:\Users
```

But this doesn't

```
> explorer C:/Users
```

Use `os.path.normpath` to convert the forward slashes into back slashes

---

Note that `abspath`, according to the docs, is implemented as `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`, so the other solution also addresses this issue.

Comment: Thanks. `abspath` and `normpath` both convert the slashes and solve the problem (apart from the unnormal exit code) while `dirname` (`split`) just doesn't care which kind of slashes it gets. (`print(os.path.dirname(r'C:\Users'))` gives `C:\\ ` and `print(os.path.dirname(r'C:/Users'))` gives `C:/` ).